# Regex with multiple options

Tags: regex, powerapps

Only have a basic understanding of Regex and some of the grouping/optionals confuse me. I'm trying to add an optional part to this.

I currently have this pattern:

```
"^(DS-\d{3,4})?$"
```

Which expects a string literal of 'DS-' and then 3 or 4 digits.

What I would like, is the 'DS-' or the '-' to be optional, so all of these would be valid:

```
DS999
DS-9999
9999
```

This would be invalid:
-999

Comment: (option1|option2)? ~ where ?=0 or 1

Answer (score 2):

use `^(DS-?)?\d{3,4}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/bHUUQG/1. What you would like, is the 'DS' or the 'DS-' to be optional, not the entire expression.